# DNS сервер windows не работает с удаленной подсетью

Tags: dns, tcp-ip, active-directory

Есть работающая доменная сеть предприятия в городе "А" со своей подсетью.
В связи с расширением компании открыли офис в городе "Б" со своей подсетью.
Настроили VPN точка-точка между двумя роутерами, доступ к сетевым ресурсам по IP адресу работает,
а по сетевым именам - нет. Адрес ДНС сервера везде указан города "А". Браузерные страницы открываются. Через NSLOOKUP DNS сервер резолвит все адреса кроме доменных имен предприятия.